# How can I make my slidershow protect its aspect ratio while shrinking?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I'm making a website and in my website there is a slidershow. When I shrink my browser it is not protecting its aspect ratio and it becomes very ugly. I can't use padding-top = x% technic because in my slidershow there is image and then its getting broken. I tried to do height = width / 2 with JavaScript but it didn't work. So is there anyone who knows how can I do it?

**The JavaScript Code That I Mentioned**

```
var slider_menu = document.getElementById('slider-menu');
var slider_menu_width = slider_menu.clientWidth;
slider_menu.clientHeight = slider_menu_width / 2;
```

**JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/ofk6qdyt/**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `onresize` listener and dynamically update size of slider?

```
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  // Your code here
})
```